# jQuery Change number inside name attribute on cloned row with multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form row with 26 inputs on it, some text some select boxes. I have a button that clones the top row, adds an increment to the row number. However i'm struggling to work out how to increment the name and ID of the cloned field elements.

Form:

```html
<tr id="CmasterRow" class="DB1_ROW">
                                                <td><span id="cnumber"> <input type="text" size="2" readonly class="form-control" id="DB1[0][A]" name="DB1[0][A]"  data-circuitNumber="0" data-EN="0"  value="0"></span></td>
                                                <td>    
                                                    <div class="input-group">                     
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DB1[0][B]" name="DB1[0][B]" data-EN="1">
                                                        
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>                                       
                                                <td>    
                                                    <div class="input-group">                     
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DB1[0][C]"   size="2" name="DB1[0][C]" data-EN="2">
                                                       
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>                                       
                                                <td>    

                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DB1[0][D]" size="4"  name="DB1[0][D]" data-EN="3">

                                                </td>                                  
                                                <td>    
                                                    <div class="input-group">                     
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DB1[0][E]" size="3"  name="DB1[0][E]" data-EN="4">

                                                    </div>
                                                </td>   
<!-- ... etc ... etc ... -->
                                                         
</tr>
```

Here's the javascript I have at the moment (the working on that clones the row)

```js
        var template = $('#CmasterRow'),
        $("#addrow").click(function () {
            var row = template.clone();
            var n = $("[data-circuitNumber]").length;
            row.find('input').val('');
            row.find('[data-circuitNumber]').val(n);
            
            row.find('input').attr('name').replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g,"[" + n + "]");
            row.find('input').attr('id').replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g,"[" + n + "]");
            
            
            row.insertBefore($('#disBoard tbody>tr:last').eq(-1));
            // saveData(); - own function not needed for this issue.
            
           
            return false;

            /* Version 1 simple row clone
             var row = $('#disBoard tbody>tr:first').clone(true);
             var n = $("[data-circuitNumber]").length;
             row.find('input').val('');
             row.find('[data-circuitNumber]').val(n);
             row.insertBefore($('#disBoard tbody>tr:last').eq(-1));
             saveData();
             return false;
             */
        });
```

I 'think' I'm on the right lines with using the .find and the .replace and the regex. I am just a little stuck of getting it to work. I did get it working (of sorts) with a single form element however that java script has been chopped and changed with the above or i would have included that workings in this post.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

To update an attribute for a node use:

```
var newValue = 'whatever'
row.find('selector').attr('your attribute', newValue);
```

Your code takes a value of an attribute, applies regex and then does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) does not replace anything in the original string and returns a new string with replaced values.

```
row.find('input').attr('name').replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g,"[" + n + "]");
row.find('input').attr('id').replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g,"[" + n + "]");
```

So the above lines basically return new values for `id` and `name`. you need to take those values and apply them as suggested by Eriks.

```
var newId=row.find('input').attr('name').replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g,"[" + n + "]");
var newName=row.find('input').attr('id').replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g,"[" + n + "]");

row.find('input').attr('id',newId);
row.find('input').attr('name',newName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Abdul and Eriks,

Answer (score 0):

```js
            row.find('input').attr('id', function (i, val) {
                val = val.replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g, "[" + n + "]");
                return val
            });

            row.find('input').attr('name', function (i, val) {
                val = val.replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g, "[" + n + "]");
                return val
            });
```

Thanks both for your help, I understand now where i was going wrong. I have completed the task by taking your input and developing the above code